# Can Debian amd64 and i386 share the same home folder?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, debian

I am planning to install Debian amd64 and i386 in the same USB HDD to boot both types of PCs.

Unfortunately, there is not enough space for the home folder, so can I share the home folder with two systems. And how about swap area and `/tmp` folder?

Comment: More appropriate for superuser but yes you can the home and tmp folders and even swap should be fine to share.

Comment: Thanks Jesus Romos. Does "More appropriate for superuser" means it better to have the some user id and group id, and user has sudo privilege? And is there any chance to cause any incompatible conflicts for the configuration files in the home folder?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can! Just make sure you are running close-to-the-same version of your programs on both of them so that the configuration files under ~/.here dont confuse each other.

If the amd64 and i386 are different installs then you can share the swap and tmp as well.

You could also share /var/log but I wouldnt recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

You can, just be sure to keep the username and `UID` number the same on both operating systems. This avoids stingy UNIX permission conflicts.

You can also share `swap` and `/tmp` if you want.